# SQL statement to pull data with dates 3 years before today

Tags: sql

I'm using a report writing system that uses SQL. The report will need to pull accounts that hasn't had any transactions in the last three years of the date the report will be ran. What statement can I use to be able to pull these records?

Comment: Can you provide some more information such as table structure? Difficult to answer your question without additional information.

Comment: `where transaction_date >= current_date - interval '3' year`

Comment: What database platform and version?